# Multisite Â&nbsp wrong encoding problem

Tags: multisite, encoding

After I upgraded multisite system from 3.5 to 3.5.1, I started having a weird encoding problem - all `&nbsp` are rendered as `Â&nbsp`.  All of my pages (as well as the DB entries) are UTF-8 encoded. All the meta tags on the pages are (automatically) set to

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

However, when I view the page, some of the characters are incorrectly displayed. Upon further examination of the request headers, it turned out that the server is setting the encoding to ISO-8859-1.

The problem seems to be that on the base website (www.blabla.com), my

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

has no effect on the browser, even with `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` set in `.htaccess` - the response header still says

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

However, on the very same install and with the same settings, my sub-directory website (www.blabla.com/sub) gets the response header as

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Changing to a different theme (TwentyTwelve) temporarily, switching off all the plugins does not solve the issue.

Comment: `<meta>` is irrelevant, don’t use it. And what the server says will be overridden by PHP. So there is some PHP code with `header()` sending the wrong charset. Make sure to disable mu-plugins too. Also, enable debug notices; maybe there is a notice sent before WordPress can send the correct header.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I'm using any mu-plugins, as there is no `mu-plugins` folder anywhere in my installation. I did enable the debug mode, and got a bunch of "`attribute_escape` deprecated" and undefined indices warnings, but would they really interfere with the encoding? I also grepped through the code, looking for a hardcoded call to iso in a `header()` call, but couldn't find any.

Comment: These notices tell me at least there is still some third-party code active. They don’t happen in a regular WordPress installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pinpointed the bug to the User Access Manager 1.2.2 (network-wide) - once disabled, everything went back to normal. I'm still not sure what exactly was causing the problem.